# How do I use notepad++ to add text to the beginning of a specific line (e.g. line 3) in multiple files?

Tags: regex, notepad++

With Notepad++, how can I add text to the beginning of a specific line (e.g. line 3) in multiple files?

Consider the following file structure:

```
File1:
this.is.the.first.key=blah
me.is.second=blahblah
blahblahblah
i.is.fourth=blahblahblahblah
j=sok
i=oakfoasskf
o=sdofkogdk
this is missing a variable
```

This structure exists in multiple files, each containing the same keys (or missing keys) while the values are translated according to the file name (one file is _en, another _de, etc.) I want to add keys to all lines that are missing them

(I saw many answers which suggested using RegEx for selecting line-beginnings, but there was nothing about choosing a **specific** line).

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++

Find what : `^([^=]*)(?!=)$`

Replace with: `KEY=$1`

Open all the files which you want to replace and Click "Replace All in All Opened Documents" button under Replace tab.

---

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lF4hM6/21) as well.

The above regex pattern looks for all the lines that doesn't have `=` symbol.

Pattern Explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^=]*                    any character except: '=' (0 or more times)
  )                        end of \1

  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    =                        '='
  )                        end of look-ahead
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: sorry for misleading, the var numbers don't actually share any common denominator (var was used just as an example). I edited my question, I hope it's more clear now

Comment: the find what is great, the replace with not so much. I need each key to be distinct (e.g. key1, key2, key3) because later on I'll need to fetch the value from the key. Is that possible to achieve somehow?