# Qt Creator placeholders

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I found out that Qt Creator can insert a license template header when creating a new file and fill certain placeholders automatically like file name and year:

```
/**
  @file   %FILENAME%
  Copyright (c) %YEAR%
*/
```

Are these placeholders documented anywhere ? Maybe in some kind of a list ?

PS: Under this bug report ([QTCREATORBUG-14726](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-14726)) Tobias Hunger commented that a new macro style of this format: `%{CurrentDate:FORMATSTRING}` is being used. But I can't find a documentation for this either!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see anything where there is a license file already stored, but on [Qt website](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tips.html#adding-a-license-header-template-for-c-code) it says this:

> Adding a License Header Template for C++ Code
>
> A file containing a license header for C++ can be specified under Tools > Options > C++ > License Template. It may contain special placeholders enclosed in %% that are replaced when generating a new file:
>
> ```
> %YEAR%: Year
> %MONTH%: Month
> %DAY%: Day of the month
> %DATE%: Date
> %USER%: Username
> %FILENAME%: File name
> %CLASS%: Class name (if applicable)
> %$VARIABLE%: Contents of environment variable VARIABLE.
> ```

which can be set in:

```
Tools->Options...->C++->File Naming
```

Comment: thanks! Do you know if there is a way to add this to files already created ?

Comment: No, but you can [do it in notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733018/how-do-i-use-notepad-to-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-specific-line-e-g-lin) fairly easy

Answer (score 3):

After some digging around the issue mention in the OP the following seems to work with QtCreator 4.2.0:

```
%{Cpp:License:FileName}
%{Env:<Environmentalvar>} E.g: %{Env:PATH}
%{CurrentDate:yyyy-MM-dd}
%{Cpp:License:ClassName}
```

From the [QtCreator Sources](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/src/plugins/cpptools/cppfilesettingspage.cpp?h=4.2#n142). It would be nice to get this properly documented.